# Adding ghost data in a pretty way

Tags: sql-server, database, rdbms

This is kinda hard to explain.

Our client wants to be able to add "Fictional data" or "Ghost data". Data that shouldn't show up unless explicitly defined. Only to be able to say "What if we had a delivery at this address". (Which they don't they just wanna pretend they did)

My first thought was to add a Boolean column to tell whether the entry is a ghost entry. But that means we'd have to include a constraint to EVERY stored procedure. or linq query we've every written and will write. This is not a good solution.

Another idea my coworker had was creating a duplicate table containing all the ghost data. That way can keep them separate. Problems arise once we realize there's relationships to the table. All these has to be duplicated too. And maintainability takes a hit cause every change we make in the normal table would have to be reflected in the "ghost" table.

Ideas?

Comment: Is this for testing where you don't want to show live/real data?

Comment: What if you set up a link table which contained only two columns, the PK of the row itself and the PK of the row from your main table as a foreign key?

Comment: Not from a development viewpoint. This is something the costumer wants. They want to be able to work with "what if's"

Answer (score 0):

You can create duplicate tables. - of course every table that could potentially hold ghost data will need a seperate table.

To get around the problem with the relations you will need to do any joins against unions of real and ghost data.

Edit: [Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/827dd/7)

Comment: unions? Is that the same as joins? If you could add a link with more info on the subject.

Comment: Answer now include link to example